# Saving the URL during registration

Tags: entities, multi-sites

So I have created a drupal multisite install with a shared user database and I would like to store the site the user has signed up on.

I have also created a view of user and I would like to filter them by site. Ideally I would like the view filter to be a dropdown, but it isn't essential.

I am already overriding the user_register_form via the template.php file, would it best to create a new text field for the user then hide and set it to the current domain via the template.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7

The best way to do is to create a new field for user registration form. Lets call the field as **domain**.

Steps:

1. Go to admin/config + **Account settings** + **Manage Fields**
2. Add new field
   [image]
   After adding
   [image]
   If you want to show this field in registration then check this
   [image]

   **NOTE**: If prefer do not show on registration form. May be there a chance to edit. Even though if your making it as disable, it can be change.

   When ever the user registration form load, alter the form using **[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)** and give the **default value** for it.

   `function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
   switch ($form_id)  {
       case 'user_register_form':
          //get field language
          $field_lang = field_language('user', 'field_user_domain');
          //assign default value
          $form['field_user_domain'][$field_lang['field_user_domain']][0]['#default_value'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
       break;
    }
   }`

   When ever the users register the domain also saved.

You can use this field in views as per your requirement.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your very clear explanation this is exactly what I needed. Thanks again :)

Comment: Welcome :) enjoy coding